# how to save data in Yii and be sure on correct saving?

Tags: php, yii, orm

Example: we have test table, which has 3 columns: id, watchers, title. 
We have a code:

```
$test = Test::model()->findByPk(1);
echo $test->watchers; // 0
$test->title = 'another';
$test->save();
```

When we call save() ir generates sql query like `"UPDATE test SET title='another', watchers='0' WHERE id='1'"`. SO, seams like everything is okay. But the problem is that if some another process will update watchers variable in the time between findByPk and save in current script, the code will generate wrong value. So:

```
$test = Test::model()->findByPk(1);
echo $test->watchers; // 0
$test->title = 'another';
//HERE WE HAVE A CODE WHICH PERFORMS FOR 1 SECOND. MEANWHILE ANOTHER PROCESS
// UPDATES TABLE WITH WATCHERS = 1
$test->save();
```

So, this code will save record's watchers field back to 0. How to overcome this? Why Yii ORM doesn't save **only** changed values? Why it tries to save all values? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest @Criesto answer, also you can use transactin (if db engine is InnoDB): http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTransaction It blocks table, so another query must "wait" before transaction commit or rollback.

Comment: @Criesto's answer is not okay because I don't want to rewrite every single piece of code where I store data. The problem is project-wide and with that approach I have to rewrite all code, not only critical. About transactions - are you sure that's a good idea to add transaction to every single update? In any case transactions won't solve the issue because the problem is in bad code generated by Yii, not in the concurency of MySQL. Patch for Yii is needed. And the fact that save() method works exactly the same way in Yii2 proves my  suggestion.

Comment: You can cretae class which extends from CActiveRecord (f.e. ActiveRecord) and extend all your models from it. So you need only change parent class for models to ActiveRecord and override save() method in ActiveRecord. Also you can override other methods which working with DB as you want, and no necessary to change whole code where you use CRUD methods.

Comment: @Taron Done exactly the same ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you get each value in `$test`, so when you do `$test->save();` every attribute gets saved with new record or the previous value it contained.

When you query `$test = Test::model()->findByPk(1);` then `$test->watchers;` will be the same value which was there when you executed the query, this value will only change (if the value of watchers was changed by another `update` query) when you do another `select` query. Hope that makes sense :P

You can try the following update method :

```
Test::model()->updateByPk(1, array(
                'title' => 'another'
            ));
```

Which will execute the following query:

```
UPDATE `test` SET `title`=:yp0 WHERE `test`.`id`=1.
Bound with :yp0='another'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle the issue as such:

```
$test = Test::model()->findByPk(1);
$test->title = 'another';

/*according to the api the second parameter only saves the columns 
  that are mentioned in the array. In this case it will save just the
  title
*/

$test->save(true,array('title'));
```

**{or}**

```
 $test = Test::model()->findByPk(1);
    $test->title = 'another';

    /*according to the api the parameter only saves the columns 
      that are mentioned in the array. In this case it will save just the
      title
    */

    $test->saveAttributes(array('title'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the best solution is to inherit and rewrite the save() method and do it's behaviour the same as it is in Yii2 (getDirtyAttributes() method). W must compar eattributes to fetched from the db attributes and save only those ones, which were modified. I've successfully implemented this and can cinfirm it works.